# Is there a way in terraform to have multiple lifecycle configuration blocks for a single AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, s3-lifecycle-policy

I am using module to create a AWS S3 bucket via terraform. This module creates a bucket with some a lot of default policies/configuration as mandated by my company. Along with that it sets some lifecycle rules using `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`.

I don't want to use those rules and they can be disabled via the inputs to the said module. But the problem is when I try to add my custom lifecycle configurations, I always get a different result each time. Sometimes my rules are applied while at other instances they are not present in the configuration.
Even the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration) says that:

> NOTE: S3 Buckets only support a single lifecycle configuration. Declaring multiple aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration resources to the same S3 Bucket will cause a perpetual difference in configuration.

What can be the way around this issue?

I cant set `enable_private_bucket` to `false`, but here is the code for the configuration resource in the module.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "pca_private_bucket_infrequent_access" {
  count  = var.enable_private_bucket ? 1 : 0

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.pca_private_bucket[0].id
}
```

Comment: You should specify multiple rules in one lifecycle configuration. And if the module does not support specifying custom rules then you should change the module.

Comment: If the module supports disabling via `count = 0` or some such, you should be able to attach a lifecycle configuration to it outside the module. But it is difficult to say without any code showing how it is configured or debugging details showing exactly what is going wrong with your configuration.

Comment: @luk2302: My team doesn't have the ownership of that module.. so any modification there will take a lot of time..
Another way around this, I suppose, can be to include the module source directly in my code but that'll be my last resort..!!

Comment: I think @theherk is right. Disable the lifecycle rule in the module call and create your own using the resource and attach it to the bucket using the output of the module.

Comment: @theherk: The `count` field is being set by another condition which I can't change.
```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "pca_private_bucket_infrequent_access" {
  # Lifecycle rule to transition CURRENT and   # NON CURRENT versions to standard-ia after specified  # number of days (enabled by default)
  count  = var.enable_private_bucket ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.pca_private_bucket[0].id
```
I cant set `enable_private_bucket` to false

Comment: @FaizKidwai: Then what did you mean when you said the rules can be disabled via inputs to the module? Just the rules themselves, within the lifecycle configuration resource? If so, then you have no option but to alter the module, for the very reason you reference in the documentation. You can either modify it to take additional rules as parameters, or allow the implementer to influence the count attribute.

Comment: My recommendation would be to change the count like to `count = var.enable_private_bucket && var.enable_lifecycle_configuration ? 1 : 0`, then by defaulting `enable_lifecycle_configuration` to `true` you would have no impact on previous implementations, but allow new ones not to add this resource.

Comment: If you cannot change the module but still use the module then you cannot achieve your goal, end of story. If you can change the module change it in a way that either lets you pass in the rules you want or lets you disable the lifecycle rule altogether enabling you to set a specific on outside of the module. There are no other feasible options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the v3 style which is deprecated but it seems to be the only way of doing it.

Here's how I have it set up where I have extra lifecycle rules using the `dynamic` block

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "cache" {
  bucket        = local.cache_bucket_name
  force_destroy = false
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name} cache"
  }
  lifecycle_rule {
    id                                     = "${local.cache_bucket_name} lifecycle rule"
    abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days = 1
    enabled                                = true
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = 1
    }
    transition {
      days          = 1
      storage_class = "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
  }
  dynamic "lifecycle_rule" {
    for_each = var.cache_expiration_rules
    content {
      id      = "${lifecycle_rule.value["prefix"]} expiration in ${lifecycle_rule.value["days"]} days"
      enabled = true
      prefix  = lifecycle_rule.value["prefix"]
      expiration {
        days = lifecycle_rule.value["days"]
      }
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```